# Determine all natural numbers divisible by 8 whose sum of digits is less than 10 and the product of digits is equal to 12.

Tags: number-theory

My first approach was, to make the product equal to 12 i.e. Our numbers should consists of factors of 12 (1, 2, 3, 4, 6)

Secondly, it should be divisible by 8, so it must be a ending with, (2, 4, 6)
and also, last 3 digit number should by divisible by 8

Getting A sum less than 10 is not a big deal, since we have Ones to cover it up.

Putting all the pieces together we will get our desire numbers (By using Hit and Trial)

We need to check at most, $^3C_{1}\times^4C_{2}\times2!$ combinations of last 3 digits
i.e 36

Comment: Well, it's not so easy to make the product equal to $12$.  I'd start by analyzing that condition.

Comment: @DonThousand Why rush the closure.  Give the OP a chance to use lulu's idea to edit his question, showing work and thereby improving the question.

Comment: @user2661923 Because answers like the one accepted with 3 upvotes happen. How someone decided to upvote this no effort question is beyond me.

Comment: @DonThousand [1] The OP is not to blame for tempate's answer. [2] The OP is new, and didn't realize that he was supposed to show work. [3] The OP explicitly stated (in effect) that he was confused and looking for help, rather than a full answer. [4] After lulu gave a hint/comment, the OP deserved the chance to edit his question, showing an attempt to follow through on lulu's idea. [5] **No one** posted a link to [this article](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question) which would have informed the OP of the need to improve his question.  ...see next comment

Comment: @DonThousand I see nothing in the standards that prohibits mathSE reviewers from citing the *how to ask a good question* article, bookmarking the question, and then returning to the question after 1 hour, to then downvote - vote to close.  At a minimum, I would give the OP 1 hour **after** someone gives him a link to the article, in order to give him a chance.  From my perspective, the fact that 90+% of the time, the OP will not improve his question is irrelevant.  The OP still deserves a chance.

Comment: @user2661923 I have Edited this Question, Is it relevant now?

Comment: I suggest examining [this article](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/33190/how-to-avoid-downvotes-for-beginners-questions/33236#33236) closely.  In particular, you haven't edited your question to provide your math background, the problem's source, any book/class theorems/solved-problems that you think might be relevant, or a legitimate detailed effort on your part to solve the problem.  I advise re-reading the very first comment, from lulu.  That is a good place to start.  Going forward, for your future mathSE questions, you now know how to positively influence mathSE reviewers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's start by using the last rule: the product of its digits is equal to 12. This is already giving us a great hint: only divisors of 12 (1, 2, 3, 4, and 6) can be digits of our number.

Next, we can think about the second clue: the sum of its digits is less than 10. Which means that, at most, our number can have 9 digits (since 0 is not a divisor of 12).

We can try to put these two clues together to see what the digits of our number look like:

- 2, 2, and 3, with as much as 2 ones.
- 4 and 3, with as much as 2 ones.
- 2 and 6, with as much as 1 one.

Now we can try to fit the first rule in: it must be divisible by 8. This means that our number must be even and, therefore, end in a 2, a 4, or a 6.

I'll let you fill in the rest of the puzzle-pieces.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/126920/discussion-on-answer-by-tempate-determine-all-natural-numbers-divisible-by-8-who).